# Wordpress wp_link_pages styling the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, themes

I'm making a wordpress theme and runned into something i can't figure out.

In comments.php

```
<?php $args = array(
    'before'           => '<p>Pages',
    'after'            => '</p>',
    'link_before'      => '',
); ?>
   <?php wp_link_pages( $args ); ?>
```

In the wordpress text editor:

```
test1
<!--nextpage-->
test2
<!--nextpage-->
```

This shows two links. Pages: 1 2
When 1 is clicked it will show "test1"
When 2 is clicked it will show "test2"

What i want add a div for each page:
When 1 is clicked  `<div id='slide'> test1 </div>`
When 2 is clicked  `<div id='slide2'> test2 </div>`

I searched google and stackoverflow but i can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks already

*This questions is still unanswered?  Add a different div for each 'page'. How can i achieve this? With jquery perhaps?*

Comment: Can you post your HTML code for test1 and test2

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Test1 and test2 is just some sample text i entered in  the wordpress text editor(used for creating a post).

Comment: yeah sorry, I think if I understood try `<div id="side">pages` in `before` instead of `p` and `</div>` in after argument instead of `</p>`

Comment: That's something i already tried. But that's the div used for the links. So it results in <div>Pages 1 2</div> I want to change the div for the content when the linked is clicked.

Comment: Well I think you would need to add the content's in that div. For example, if you have `posts` , put them in the specified div

Comment: That's not the result i want. I want them both to be different but the ammount of pages is defined by the ammount of nextpage tags u use in the editor. I want it to add a div for every page. As an example: <div id="1">test1</div> and <div id="2">test2</div>.

Comment: The code structure right now: <div id="div1" class="section"> <div class="slide">test1</div></div> How i want it to be: <div id="div1" class="section"> <div class="slide">test1</div> <div class="slide">test2</div></div>

Comment: Is it possible to edit the <!--nextpage--!> function in functions.php of my theme?